# Error when trying to run a minitest unit test

Tags: ruby, minitest

I get the following error when trying to run a minitest unit test with `ruby test/test_foo.rb`:

````
Warning: you should require 'minitest/autorun' instead.
Warning: or add 'gem "minitest"' before 'require "minitest/autorun"'
From:
  /home/emile/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/minitest/autorun.rb:15:```
````

test_foo.rb looks like this:

```
require 'minitest/autorun'

class TestFoo < MiniTest::Test
 #stuf
end
```

My Gemfile does contain `gem 'minitest'` and test_foo.rb does contain `require 'minitest/autorun'`, yet I still get the warning.

Is this a bug? Any ideas?

Comment: Run your test with `bundle exec ruby test/test_foo.rb` to make sure ruby uses your bundled minitest version. If you just run it with `ruby test/test_foo.rb`, you'll use your global gemset instead of the local bundle.

Comment: I've interepreted the warning literally and added the line `gem 'minitest'` before the line `require 'minitest/autorun'`, and that seems to work. Odd, or is this expected?

Comment: That's not really how `gem` is supposed to be used, I'd say. Try running it with `bundle exec` instead, and see what happens then.

Comment: Frost, that works. But I don't understand why it works. I get what `bundle exec` does, but I've assumed I only have one minitest version. So my Gemfile simply states `gem minitest` (it doesn't specify a specific version). Might my assumption be incorrect? How can I check whether I've got a different version in my global gemset?

Comment: if you run `gem list minitest` in your terminal, you'll see all globally installed versions of minitest.

Comment: Ok, so `gem list minitest` produces `*** LOCAL GEMS *** minitest (5.0.6)`. Not quite sure what the "LOCAL" alludes to, since you're talking about "globally installed versions" (sorry, the questions are beginning to detract from the main question, but I'm learning quite a bit here from you). With reference to the main question: if there's only one version, why should it be necessary to execute with `bundle exec`?

Comment: I'm not really sure. Try to have a look at the `/home/emile/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/minitest/autorun.rb` file, around line 15, for instance.

Comment: Thanks for the help Frost. Do you want to answer so I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run your test using `bundle exec ruby test/test_foo.rb` to make sure you use your bundled gems (in this case minitest).

Just running `ruby test/test_foo.rb` will use your globally installed Rubygems.

If you want to dig around a little more, try looking in `/home/emile/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/minitest/autorun.rb`, around line 15.

Comment: Thank you for this. I keep forgetting this as well. :)

Answer (score 4):

▲

> I've interepreted the warning literally and added the line gem 'minitest' before the line require 'minitest/autorun', and that seems to work. Odd, or is this expected?

This is expected. It tells ruby to use the gem version and not the standard library version.